# C# - I can't seem to have the results of the square of 10 numbers displayed on a label in a windows Form line by line

Tags: c#, label

I have a window form application with a button and a label.
After a push of the button, the label needs to display the square of the numbers 1 till 10. This needs to be displayed line by line.
 This is the code I have so far:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] sqrNumbers = new int[10];
        for (int i = 1; i != sqrNumbers.Length; i++)

        {

            sqrNumbers[i] =  i * i;

            lblSquares.Text = (sqrNumbers[i]).ToString()+ Environment.NewLine;

        }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. As I am new to programming, I can't seem to figure this out. I scoured the net to find an answer bt haven't found what I was looking for. Thanks for helping me out on this.

Kr,

Jay

Comment: You're reassigning the label text each time through the loop, so it'll only display the last one.  Instead, build the string, then assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead: (Edit this is probably safer)

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    int[] sqrNumbers = new int[10];
    String text = "";
    for (int i = 1; i != sqrNumbers.Length; i++)

    {

        sqrNumbers[i] =  i * i;

        text += (sqrNumbers[i]).ToString()+ Environment.NewLine;

    }

    lblSquares.Text = text;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.µI'll give it a go and let you know if this solves the problem.

Comment: Hi @Someone, Thanks! It works. I'll continue with the rest of my small app. You've been a great help thanks.

Comment: @Jay could you possibly select my answer as the answer then?? ^^ np.

Answer (score 0):

```
 lblSquares.Text = (sqrNumbers[i]).ToString()+ Environment.NewLine;
```

overwrites the value of lblSquares.Text

```
lblSquares.Text += (sqrNumbers[i]).ToString()+ Environment.NewLine;
```

Will preserve the value and add to it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx